# php mail form input error

Tags: php, forms, email, input

Hello I am using contant mail form on my page. It was build in defaut tempate and it looks like this:

```
    <form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contactform_main" style="font-size:14px">
                <ol>
                  <li>
                    <label for="name">Meno</label>
                    <input id="name" name="name" class="text" required/>
                  </li>
                  **<li>
                    <label for="number">Tel.</label>
                    <input id="number" name="number" class="text" />
                  </li>**
                  <li>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="text" required />
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <label for="subject">Predmet</label>
                    <input id="subject" name="subject" value="<?php echo $_GET['subject'] ?>" class="text"/>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label for="message">SprĂˇva</label>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="6" cols="50" ><?php echo $_GET['text'] ?></textarea>
                  </li>
                  <li class="buttons">
                    <input type="submit" name="imageField" value="OdoslaĹĄ" class="send" style="cursor:pointer" />
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                  </li>
                </ol>
              </form>
```

The second input (number} is  code which I added myself. Here is the important php part which procced the form

```
    $values = array ('name','number','email','message');
        $required = array('name','number','email','message');


        $your_email = "some@mail.com";
        $email_subject = "NovĂˇ sprĂˇva: ".$_POST['subject'];
        $email_content = "Text sprĂˇvy:\n";

        foreach($values as $key => $value){
          if(in_array($value,$required)){
            if ($key != 'subject' && $key != 'company') {
            //  if( empty($_POST[$value]) ) { echo 'PLEASE FILL IN REQUIRED FIELDS'; exit; }
            }
}
            $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
          }
```

After I put number in values array. My form crash on submit, because of the empty value condtion. If i remove this condition the form is sent but number is still empty.
Can you tell me why the input number is not sending any value ? Thanks

Comment: `$required = array('name',number','email','message');` -- read this line again. You're missing a single-quote for the `number`.

Comment: thans for notice but the single qute mark is here i just acidentely removed it here. But the form is sitll not working.

Answer (score 0):

Well you fixed that

The code you have shown are missing a closing } for the foreach loop now

Comment: sorry I just copied code wrong. Now it shoukd be fine, anaway it is not syntax error because my email is sent without error but input number is always empty.

Comment: i would start by doing a print_r($_POST) to see if the data you want is really there before continuing to try to debug it